# How can I tether a camera to a laptop, to show its menus and functions for teaching purposes?

Tags: tethering

I understand the tethering process and have connected my Nikon D90 to my laptop.  I am able to see images that are on the memory card just fine.  My question is this:  I am teaching a class on camera functions, and I want to be able to show on my laptop the menu and various functions of my camera. I will be connecting the laptop to a projector, so it will be available to all students at once. It would be so much easier to show everyone where to find settings, how to use manual exposure, etc.  Is that even possible this way, or is there another way to connect these devices I have not considered?  I also have a Nikon D500 with more sophisticated connection capability.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11):

I think your best bet would be to use the HDMI output of the camera to connect it directly to the projector. If you have multiple inputs on the projector, you should even be able to switch between showing the camera's screen and the laptop while still having the camera connected to the laptop through USB for tethering. The best case scenario would be if the projector can show picture from the two inputs side by side or overlaid in some way.

This way you can show the information display and menus to explain settings and take pictures which the people will see on the projection screen as if they're looking at the camera's screen. You can always switch to the laptop to show the pictures in more detail or to show slides for your presentation (if you have any).

Comment: Does the D90, first introduced in 2008, even have an HDMI port?

Comment: @MichaelClark Yes, it does, but even if it didn't, a D500 is available as the author said.

Comment: That is a very helpful response.  Thanks so much.  My projector has a USB connector, too, so I may be able to use the three together in a creative way.  I will check it out.

Comment: I doubt that the USB on the projector would be useful with the camera - I bet it's meant for simple tasks like showing pictures from a flash drive. What model is the projector anyway?